# Invalid sender error in MetaMask with private network in Azure ethereum BaaS

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumj, metamask, microsoft-azure

I had implemented Ethereum Blockchain as a service from Microsot azure. The client i am using is from Metamask. I am not able to send ether from one wallet to other and i get an error Invalid sender .
Sending ether fro[image]m Network to the wallet works fine.
Can you please help.[image]
Thanks,
Phani

Comment: I answered this question, so you should mark it answered so the system will stop showing the question to people, looking for answers.

Comment: Any solution here? I have the same problem with MetaMask 3.9

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Azure is deploying an old, somewhat outdated Ethereum client that does not implement [EIP 155 replay protections](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155), which slightly changes the signature format in a way that has a nice migration path for clients to update before signers, but not for signers to update before clients.

MetaMask has an issue for adding the ability to turn off EIP 155 Replay Protection protection for these older chains, you can track progress there:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/1357

In the meanwhile, you can work around this by manually installing the last-compatible version of MetaMask, which was v3.5.2:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/releases/tag/v3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be broken from the version of 25 April 2017 (3.5.4?). There is a new version already (3.6.0) but the bug is still there. I was having no trouble deploying contracts to Azure before the 25th.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with latest chrome extension and it works like a charm.
Update your Chrome extension.
Version: 4.1.2